$D^2(f(\boldsymbol{x}))=m^2f(\boldsymbol{x})$ Where is my answer wrong?
Let $f(\boldsymbol{x}) = f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) $ be a homogeneous function of degree $ m $, i.e., a function that satisfies $ f(t\boldsymbol{x}) = t^m f(\boldsymbol{x}) $ and $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ class. In that case prove that
$$
\left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^r f = m(m-1) \cdots (m-r+1) f(\boldsymbol{x})
$$
I thought about this problem as follows.In the case of $r=1$, it is assumed.
Of course, this is incorrect. However, I still don't understand where my answer is wrong.
I understand the correct answer, I just want to know what is wrong with my answer.

As I said on your previous question, $Df$ is $(m-1)$-homogeneous, so $$D^2 f = DDf = (m-1)Df = m(m-1)f$$

I understand that your answer is correct. However, I cannot figure out which part of my argument is wrong.

What does "Let $D$ correspond to $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ ..." even mean?

I defined $D$as a map that corresponds $f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ to $x_1 D_1 f(x_1, \ldots, x_n) + \cdots + x_n D_n f(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$.

BTW, put in the question that you understand the correct answer, you just want to know what is wrong with your answer. That will keep people, who are volunteering to help you, from duplicating stuff you know.

"Corresponds" means nothing here. What do you mean?

So you mean it maps (or send) $f$ to that other function?

@ThomasAndrews From the twin question where they mention the problem is from a Japanese book, OP might only speak English as their second language, so I wouldn't be too harsh on them about grammar and stuff. I thought their questions were understandable enough, but maybe my standards are low to be fair.

Your mistake is simply that you're applying $D(f,a) = mf(a)$ twice without reminding yourself that the $m$ depends on $f$. Rather, if you write $m_g$ for the degree of a homogeneous function $g$, then you have $$D(g, a) = m_g g(a)$$
and so, if we :
$$D(a\mapsto D(f,a), b) = m_{a \mapsto D(f,a)} D(f,b) = m_{a \mapsto D(f,a)} m_f f(b) = (m_f - 1)m_f f(b)$$
Edit: this answer assumes the following interpretation for $D$, which yields the problem's author's result: $$D(f,a) := \left(a_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + a_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(a)$$ rather than $$Df : a \mapsto \left(x_1 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)f(a)$$
which instead preserves the degree of homogeneity of $f$, leading to a $m^r$ instead of the falling factorial present here.
See $\left( x_1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + \cdots + x_n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)^r f = m(m-1) \cdots (m-r+1) f(x)$ for more context (thanks to Brian Moehring for noticing the difference!).

I understand now. Thank you for answering several times. I will try to ask questions that are easier to understand.

Glad to have been of help! @Maaaa
